# Theory of undirected graphs splits in two cases

Tags: logic, graph-theory, set-theory, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L} := \{ R \}$ be a language with $R$ a binary relation. Let $T := \{ \forall x \forall y (x R y \to y R x) \}$ be the theory of undirected graphs in the language $\mathcal{L}$.

For $x, y$ we call a path of length $n$ a sequence $x = a_0, a_1, ..., a_n = y$ with $a_i R a_{i + 1}$ for $i = 0, ..., n-1$. A graph is called disconnected if there are $x, y$ such that there is no path of length $n$ between them for all $n \geq 1$. The diameter of a graph is the length of the longest shortest path between two vertices (or $\infty$ if the graph is disconnected).

The exercise now asks me to do the following:

For any theory $T' \supset T$ exactly one of the following cases holds:

1. there is a model of $T'$ that is disconnected;
2. there is an integer $N \geq 1$ such that all models $G$ of $T'$ are of diameter at most $N$.

It is easy to show that one of the two assertions excludes the other. But I have a bit of trouble to show that any theory must satisfy one of the cases.

My first idea was to find a set of formulas that describe disconnected graphs and then use the compactness theorem to prove that a model exists. But it seems rather unlikely to me that such a set of formulas exists.

My second idea was then to show that if 2. fails there is a graph of the form $0 < 1 < 2 < ... < -2 < - 1 $ (here the vertex set is $\mathbf{Z}$ and all negative integers are strictly greater than the nonnegative integers, while edges exist between successors). Such a graph could maybe extracted by taking vertices $a_n, b_n$ in a model of $T'$ such that the shortest path between them is of length $n$ and then find "limit vertices". But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Can anyone help me on that?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course, I'll edit it.

Comment: Why and how is this a set theory question?

Answer (score 2):

Adjoin two new constant symbols $a$ and $b$ to the language, and consider the theory $T''$ consisting of your $T'$ plus, for each $n$, the sentence saying there's no path of length $n$ from $a$ to $b$.  If this theory $T''$ has a model, then that's a disconnected model of $T'$, because $a$ and $b$ are in different components.  If $T''$ has no model, then by compactness, there's $N$ such that $T'$ plus the additional axioms for $n\leq N$ has no model.  In this case, all models of $T'$ have diameter at most $N$.

Comment: I have a question on your proof: The compactness argument tells me that there is a $N$ such that $T' \cup \{ \neg (\exists a_1 \cdots \exists a_{n-1} (x R a_1 \wedge ... \wedge a_{n - 1} R y) : n \leq N \}$ has no model. But hence we know that in any model of $T'$ the distance between $a$ and $b$ is at most $N$. How does this imply that the diameter of the model is at most $N$?

Comment: If the finite subtheory of $T''$ you mentioned has no model, then if $G\models T'$, for any interpretation for $a,b$ in $G$, $G$ doesn't satisfy the formula "$a$ and $b$ are at distance at least $N$", therefore it satisfies "$a$ and $b$ are at distance at most $N$"